# Nonnegative series converges implies terms decay exponentially?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence with nonnegative terms ($a_n\geq 0$). If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n < \infty$, does this imply that there exists $\alpha<1$ such that $a_n \leq \alpha^n$ for all but finitely-many $n$?

If the root test is successful, i.e., $\alpha=\limsup \left|a_n\right|^{1/n}<1$, then by definition of the $\limsup$, we know that for any $\epsilon$ there exists $N$ such that $\left| a_n \right|^{1/n} <\alpha + \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Thus, $a_n < (\alpha + \epsilon)^n$ for $n\geq N$ and $\epsilon$ can be chosen so that $\alpha+\epsilon<1$.

However, if the root test is inconclusive ($\alpha=1$), then we cannot use this argument to find $\alpha$. Is there another way, or is the statement false?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Consider $a_n = 1/n^2$.

Comment: Thanks. $\lim \frac{(1/\alpha)^n}{n^2}=\infty$ for any $\alpha<1$.